How to persist an AWS CLI session on a non AWS server?
On my local development machine, I am developing a .NET app with the AWS SDK to use a particular service.
In order for the app to communicate with AWS, I first run the AWS CLI with a particular IAM user that has been set up prior.
By default, this IAM user which is set up for this purpose has a 1 hour expiry, meaning that after one hour of running the aws configure SSO command it will stop working.
Eventually I wish to deploy the app for use on a web server that is outside Amazon's environment. I imagine this involves installing the AWS CLI and running the same command initially. But what I don't want to happen is for the session to ever expire. Otherwise a human would have to manually remote into the server run the command and validate the MFA code and so on.
I cannot find any information online on how to set up a permanent AWS connection (whether the session refreshes automatically or the original one persists is of no matter). The only resources I can find relate to "long term credentials" but the documentation suggests this is bad practice.
So how does one do this in real life? How can AWS CLI  be configured to always run on a server without having to worry about session expiry?

Could you make a credential process script that refreshes SSO tokens automatically?

@BigMistake that would be a logical step but part of the process involves MFA validation via a browser

Why not create an IAM user without 1 hour expiry? Perhaps you can use a secret key, and rotate it whenever you need to, but have a persistent IAM user.

@bigMistake my understanding is that IAM users need an expiry time?

@ Notaras my understanding is that it is not required, and I have used long-lasting IAM accounts. Where are you seeing a max expiry time for the user?

From What is AWS Identity and Access Management Roles Anywhere? - IAM Roles Anywhere:

You can use AWS Identity and Access Management Roles Anywhere to obtain temporary security credentials in IAM for workloads such as servers, containers, and applications that run outside of AWS. Your workloads can use the same IAM policies and IAM roles that you use with AWS applications to access AWS resources. Using IAM Roles Anywhere means you don't need to manage long-term credentials for workloads running outside of AWS.
To use IAM Roles Anywhere, your workloads must use X.509 certificates issued by your certificate authority (CA). You register the CA with IAM Roles Anywhere as a trust anchor to establish trust between your public-key infrastructure (PKI) and IAM Roles Anywhere.


Use IAM Roles to provide secure AWS access on non-AWS systems. If IAM Roles are not an option, save credentials in AWS Secrets Manager or Parameter Store and change them on a regularly.
Useful links:
IAM Roles
AWS Secrets Manager
AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store

None of these are actually helpful in this case. You can't assume a role without IAM credentials (or SSO/IDP credentials) in the first place and you can't access secrets in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store without AWS credentials either. Solution is to use IAM Roles Anywhere (preferred) or long-term IAM User credentials (definitely not preferred).
